# parameter to check is null or is not null in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have one table 
  Employee

```
       Eno     ename   image

       1        aaa     a.jpg
       2        bbb     b.jpg
       3        ccc     null
       4        ddd     null
```

I pass the parameter to the query

```
   declare @a varchar(10)

   select * from employee where ?
```

? if i pass image is not null mean i want all employee details who have image other wise

i want image is null employee details who not have image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from employee 
where (@a is null and image is null)
    or (@a is not null and image is not null )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I think you want

```
WHERE     (@a is null AND image is NULL)
   OR (@a is not null AND image is not NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is short and sweet but not [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) so it won't perform well:

```
select *
    from employee
    where coalesce(image,'') = coalesce(@a,'')
```

For better performance, I'd go with:

```
if @a is not null
    select *
        from employee
        where image = @a
else
    select *
        from employee
        where image is null
```